# Does anyone know what this rubber thing I found on the tub in my dishwasher is?

Tags: dishwasher

[image: unknown 3 inch rubber thing flat with two... Teeth?]

Last night I was emptying my KitchenAid KDFE104DSS5 dishwasher when I found this on the tub. I looked all over inside it trying to figure out where the heck it came from. It's about 3 inches long.

I have a 2½-year-old child so it's possible he found it somewhere and stuck it in the dishwasher but even so, I don't recognize it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about home improvement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked on reddit's whatisthisthing and they identified it as a rubber foot from my IKEA cheese grater.[image]

Comment: _That_ is some serious sleuthing! Very impressive. (Assuming you have an IKEA cheese grater, of course... :) Please also accept your answer (by clicking the check mark), this tells people this issue has a resolution and prevents the system from bumping the question to the top of the list every few months.

Comment: Reddit Whatisthisthing is an amazing tool. I tried to accept it as the answer but I can't for 48 hours because it's my own answer.

Comment: Was you cheese grater missing the part?

Comment: Yes, it was, JACK.